# Adding Business Process Types to publications via script

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

I did create a script to add 800 `TtmWebsite`, 800 `TtmWebApplication` and 800 `TtmMapping` to our 800 Publications during a migration.

Now we have the problem that we would need to select a Business Process Type manually to each of the publication once.

The initial view of one publication after opening the properties:
[image]

The available business process types:
[image]

Question: Is there a way to add Business Process Types automatically via script so we wont have to do all the work manually? Prefered with Powershell cmdlets from SDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Core Service API to programatically modify the Publications.

Comment: +1 to Rick. Use Jacques’ script to do it from https://gist.github.com/JacquesKors/40c64229d8c021d32e637a46aa11c4a0#file-setpublicationbpts-ps1 works like charm

Comment: You need to install core service powershell module and then run the script. You can see how to install core service powershell module at https://vikaskumarblogs.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/working-with-sdl-tridionweb-core-service-powershell-module/

Comment: Yes that's it many thanks to you and @Jacques! I already had the core service powershell module installed on my content manager server and i am looking into the cmdlet.

Comment: Script execution finished, all Publications migrated successfully.